# Submit a form and fire parent method when child emitted event is received in Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, emit

I have a parent container of App.vue. In App.vue I have a `<form></form>`. Inside of that form I have a child component. Within the child I am using a custom button component.
App.vue --> Parent
UserInfo.vue --> Child
BaseButton.vue --> Child within User.Info.vue

In UserInfo.vue I use the BaseButton like so:

```
<base-button @click="sendData" />
```

UserInfo -> sendData()

```
sendData() {
  console.log('here')
  this.$emit('send-data-to-parent');
},
```

Form in App.vue

```
 <form @send-data-to-parent="submitThisForm">
    <user-info/>
 </form>
```

submitThisForm()

```
 submitThisForm() {
      console.log('test')
    }
```

When I click the button I see the `console.log('here')` in the console but I am not seeing the `console.log('test')` from the `App.vue` `submitThisForm()` method.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@send-data-to-parent="submitThisForm"

is on your form element. Try to put in to the component, like:

```
 <form>
    <user-info @send-data-to-parent="submitThisForm"/>
 </form>
```

Working example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-panna-sxx6k3?file=/src/components/Parent.vue

Comment: your example is working well. Will this still allow me to submit the form itself since no event exists on it?

Comment: Yepp, check my updated example. Although your approach seems weird. Im not sure why would you submit a form from the child component in the first place.

Comment: I will have multiple child components passing data up to the parent root to submit the form. The form is broken out into various components that all contain data that need to be submitted together in the parent form. Am I going about this the wrong way? I am open to a better method.